# Direct sum and modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Can we always write $M \cong N \oplus M/N$ as $R$-modules ? If not, then under what conditions on $M$, the direct sum holds ?

Comment: Equality doesn't make sense. What do you really mean?

Comment: Sorry for '='. I wanted to mean 'isomorphic'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This question has almost certainly been asked before, but it seemed easier to just type this up than search for a previous answer).

There is always an exact sequence

$$0 \to N \to M \to M/N \to 0$$

I will state when this sequence is split exact (as pointed out in the comments, this is not the only possibility for which $M \cong N \oplus M/N$). Some cases when it is split:

i) $M/N$ is projective
ii) $N$ is injective

Beyond these two cases, there is not much more that can be said in general (edit: as Pete L. Clark mentions, these are both special cases of $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M/N,N) = 0$). Notice that this is not really a condition on $M$, but rather on the embedding $N \hookrightarrow M$ (or the quotient $M/N$).

Comment: Dear @user115654, isn't the splitting condition slightly stronger than the condition $M=N\oplus M/N$?

Comment: @Brenin Aren't they equivalent? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

Comment: "This question has almost certainly been asked before" Yes, 20 times (for abelian groups in particular, which are Z-modules).

Comment: @ir7: I'm not sure exactly what $=$ means in $M = N \oplus M/N$, but the condition given in the wikipedia article that you link to is stronger than just $M \cong N \oplus M/N$.  There are indeed examples in which this isomorphism holds ("abstractly": i.e., it does not fit into the right commutative diagram) and the sequence is nonsplit.

Comment: "Beyond these two cases, there is really nothing more that can be said in general."  Well, that's certainly not true.  E.g. one can say that the sequence splits if $\operatorname{Ext}^1(N,M/N) = 0$.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark I see. Thank you.

Comment: @Brenin, Pete: Of course, you are right. I was assuming that the OP was not asking for an abstract isomorphism - if this were the case, then I really don't know anything that can be said in general!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes, but it's still not so clear how to find the 20 previous questions. What should be done in such cases? (Of course, now that I have written an answer, I will link to it in the future)

Comment: (In my last comment, I got the arguments mixed up: it should read $\operatorname{Ext}^1(M/N,N)$.)

Comment: @user115654: there are some conditions which ensure that the abstract isomorphism implies the splitting of the sequence.  For instance this holds for finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.  It may well also hold for finitely generated modules over a Noetherian ring. (I taught a course on homological algebra last year at this time; unfortunately these kind of technical sepcifics are already departing from my brain...)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Yes, but I wanted to avoid specializing the ring if at all possible (the OP even wanted only conditions on $M$ itself). Thank you for your comments though, in particular reminding me about $\text{Ext}$: I'll update the answer to include that

Comment: I didn't see the focus on $M$.  In that case the answer [to the splitting question, not the isomorphism question!] is: it is necessary and sufficient that $M$ be semisimple.  Of course this does not do much more than provide the definition of the property being asked about...

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true. Consider the cyclic of order 4. It is a Z-module. Let N be the subgroup of order 2, then you get a counter example.